# WPF twoway binding conversation errors are hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind a DataRowView to controls on my windows.

Initialization code:

```
...
row = query.DefaultView[0];
DataContext = row;
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Price, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When the TextBox lose focus it try to update a row. Sometimes it fail because the Price column is integer. But instead of throwing an error it just write this to debug console:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value
>   'dfddddddf' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=Price;
>   DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=35888470); target element is
>   'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   FormatException:'System.FormatException:

How to bring this error back to light? How to catch it and throw? Why it swallow this error silently masking an exception?

I know that it can be solved with field format specification in a binding. I will write it but I still wan't to have a life buoy which will protect me from sudden conversation errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to catch these types of errors. However, in this case your ViewModel `Price` value didn't change so you don't need to worry about invalid values. You can try to use validation (the thing that should have surrounded the textbox with red when the exception fires silently) [Some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you can do to control the behavior is to define your own converter with the logic you want:

```
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int price = (int)value;
        return price.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = (string)value;
        int price;
        if (!int.TryParse(text, out price))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid value for Price!");
            return 0; //Some default value
        }

        return price;
    }
}
```

In this case the price will be replaced by 0 if it is not a valid int. You could also throw an exception but this will crash the whole application.

Another way is to set this logic into a specific `TextBox` control or on the ViewModel side (set the `Price` type to string and manage the conversion in the ViewModel).